# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.webkit.CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies

Tags: android, cookies, nosuchmethoderror

I use the following code in my app to accept cookies in a webview:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();
CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
```

Running this on an Android 4.x it runs fine. But I also tested it on a phone using 2.3.6 and there it crashes with the following stack trace:

```
10-13 22:34:20.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2371): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 22:34:20.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2371): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.webkit.CookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies
10-13 22:34:20.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at de.fblike.facebook.FacebookActivity.onCreate(FacebookActivity.java:28)
10-13 22:34:20.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-13 22:34:20.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-13 22:34:20.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-13 22:34:20.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-13 22:34:20.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-13 22:34:20.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 22:34:20.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-13 22:34:20.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-13 22:34:20.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 22:34:20.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-13 22:34:20.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
10-13 22:34:20.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
10-13 22:34:20.519: E/AndroidRuntime(2371):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So I'm asking myself: How can I repair this? Seems as if 2.3.6 does not support this method.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, eventually solved it by this patch:

platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemCookieManager.java:

```
         cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

          //REALLY? Nobody has seen this UNTIL NOW?
 -        cookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);

          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
 +            cookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
              cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(webView, true);
          }
      }
```

It was painful..

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation, you will see that this method was introduced at API12 (Android 3.1).  You must increase your minSdk version.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setAcceptFileSchemeCookies%28boolean%29)

Comment: You could examine the source and take it from there?